# Skipping Array Element When Row is Equal to Column

Tags: java, arrays, input, skip

I am a beginner to Java--I want to construct a 2D array that takes votes as a user's input. I've been trying to make sure the user cannot enter "votes" for themself--I have tried using

```
&& col != row
```

In the for loop but this does not seem to work. My current for loop is this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < Vote.length; row++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter "+ this.TeamMember[row]+"'s votes, points must add up to 100:");
            System.out.println();

            for (int col=0; col < this.Vote[row].length && col != row; col++ )
            { 
                System.out.println("Enter "+this.TeamMember[row]+ "'s points for "+ this.TeamMember[col]+":");
                this.Vote[row][col] = scan.nextInt();
            }
```

Is there a way to skip data entries for when the row in a two-dimensional array equals the column?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting that condition inside the inner for loop

```
if(row != col){
   // inner for loop
}
```

Comment: This is honestly probably the way to go, as it reads cleaner than my answer. The alternative, however, is equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an if-conditional and a `continue` statement to skip the current iteration of the for loop.

Inside your inner for loop, immediately check `if (col == row)`, and if so, `continue;`.

EDIT: You should also take out the `&& col != row` conditional in the inner for loop. That will kill your for loop early.

Comment: Yes, thank you! That was really helpful and the loop compiles correctly now.